# Pascal IDE for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ide, pascal

i'm a beginner Pascal programmer and I recently migrated to the Mac OS X. Today I spent many hours searching for a good Pascal IDE for this OS and found nothing. I used to write code with Geany on Windows and it worked like a charm, I also enjoyed the compiling and running capacity of Geany.

Do you know any Geany-like IDE or at least one that highlights, compiles and runs pascal code on the Mac OS X?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People use XCode with a suitable set of templates, but XCode lost pascal syntax highlighting a way back. There are other options:

- [Pascal Gladiator](http://www.thealchemistguild.com/pascalgladiator/)
- [Lightweight IDE](http://www.ragnemalm.se/lightweight/)

But I also still like Lazarus best.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try **Lazarus**, integrated development environment for Free Pascal.

http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/

Comment: Lazarus worked, thank you very much. I will use it from now but i think that it's a little bit too messy.

I was trying to make Sublime Text compile and run pascal code by creating a new Build System. I tried the following:

{
 "cmd": ["fpc", "$file"],
 "selector" : "source.pas",
 "path" : "/usr/local/bin"
}

but it didn't work, do you know why is that?

Answer (score 2):

@Thiago: Try with only { "cmd": ["fpc", "$file"]}

Comment: This is more like a comment. Please give a detailed answer. Also read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Hello and welcome.  This isn't really an answer to the question, but is a comment to another answer.  You can't leave comments until you have 50 rep.  I feel your pain.  When you have 50 rep, please leave things like this as comments :)

Comment: As you wrote, GHC, 50 reps are needed to comment, but the people should not wait for the help until I've got 50 reps. Is there another wayto manage this issue?

Answer (score 1):

http://freepascal.org/down/i386/macosx.var

I like Free Pascal the most, for beginning I believe it is the best because you don't have too much fancy GUI features to distract you from programming for beginners (algorithms, procedural thinking...).

I didn't try to run this on Mac but it should work... I have used Free Pascal on Linux and Windows with satisfaction.